# nullptr not declared in scope when compiling on mac

Tags: c++, arduino, interrupt, nullptr

I'm trying to use the "[Yet Another PCInt Library](https://github.com/paulo-raca/YetAnotherArduinoPcIntLibrary/tree/master/src)" for enabling pin change interrupts on my Arduino mega 2560. In the Arduino IDE, the code compiles fine on windows, but fails on a mac. It gives an error code stating:

```
 nullptr not declared in this scope
 attachInterrupt(pin, (callback)func, nullptr, mode, trigger_now);
                      ^
```

How can I get this to compile on OS X in the arduino IDE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[nullptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/nullptr) was introduced into the C++11 standard, and it does not exist in any earlier standards.
My best guess is that your arduino IDE is not configured to compile against the C++11 standard.

You may want to ensure that `avr-g++` is given the flag `--std=c++11` or higher.