# nullptr not declared in this scope class template - C++

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, templates

I'm trying to create a class template called Vector, which is used to create dynamic arrays of any type. When my default constructor is called, it creates a new array, and calls a method initialize which initializes all the values of the dynamic array to null by using nullptr. For some reason, when compiling I get the error: `'nullptr' was not declared in this scope` at that line. What could be the issue?

Also any feedback on my class would be good. I haven't tested it yet due to this error but I am hoping it will be able to handle any type of array successfully, especially arrays of objects.

Vector.h:

```
#ifndef VECTOR_H
#define VECTOR_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Vector
{
    public:
        Vector(int size = 10);
        ~Vector();

        void initialize(int from);
        void expand();
        void push(const T &element);
        int size(){return this->nrofel;}

        T& operator[](const int index);


    private:
        T **data;
        int capacity;
        int nrofel;

};

template <class T>
Vector<T>::Vector(int size){

    this->capacity = size;
    this->nrofel = 0;
    this->data = new T*[this->capacity];

    initialize(this->nrofel);

}

template <class T>
T& Vector<T>::operator[](const int index){

    if(index < 0 || index >= this->nrofel){

        throw("Out of bounds.");

    }

    return *this->data[index];

}

template <class T>
void Vector<T>::initialize(int from){

    for(size_t i = from; i < capacity; i++){

        this->data[i] = nullptr;

    }

}

template <class T>
Vector<T>::~Vector(){

    for(size_t i = 0; i < capacity; i++){

        delete this->data[i];

    }
    delete[]this->data;
}


template <class T>
void Vector<T>::expand(){

    this->capacity *= 2;

    T ** tempData = new T*[this->capacity];

    for(size_t i = 0; i < this->nrofel; i++){

        tempData[i] = this->data[i];

    }

    this->data = tempData;

    initialize(this->nrofel);

}

template <class T>
void Vector<T>::push(const T& element){

    if(this->nrofel >= this->capacity){

        this->expand();

    }

    this->data[this->nrofel++] = new T(element);

}


#endif // VECTOR_H
```

Comment: Please show how you are trying to use this, because I cannot reproduce the error: https://godbolt.org/z/kPDoQ5

Comment: @UnholySheep I have not tried to use it yet as I get a compiler error when I try to build it, error is: nullptr was not declared in this scope. As I look at the build messages, I see another warning (not error): identifier nullptr is a keyword in C++11 [-Wc++0x-compat]. I am using CodeBlocks.

Comment: You are using an older C++ version that doesn't know the keyword `nullptr`. Tell your compiler to use C++11. For example with `-std=c++11`, not sure how this can be done in CodeBlocks however.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nullptr not declared in scope when compiling on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37822826/nullptr-not-declared-in-scope-when-compiling-on-mac)